# How I can pass this variable to use it from my module?

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6, puppeteer

I've set a basic puppeteer code to automate chrome. And I'm trying to pass the `page` variable as parameter to my module method using `mymodule.foo(page)` but it fails throwing the error you can see below:

*The goal is to be able to use puppeteer objects like `page` from other modules.*

```
E:\scripts\node\myproject\mymodule.js:3
    await page.evaluateOnNewDocument(() => {
          ^^^^

SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
    at createScript (vm.js:80:10)
    at Object.runInThisContext (vm.js:139:10)
    at Module._compile (module.js:607:28)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:654:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:556:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:499:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:491:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:587:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (E:\scripts\node\myproject\app.js:3:18)
PS E:\scripts\node\myproject>
```

This is the file `app.js`:

```
// app.js
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

const mymodule = require('./mymodule');

(async () => {
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
    headless: false,
  });
  const page = await browser.newPage();

  await mymodule.foo(page);

  await browser.close();
})();
```

This is the file `mymodule.js`:

**UPDATE:** I've updated this file to add `async` to the `foo` function. But then If I try to use `await page.goto('http://www.google.com');` with await I get the same error. So I tried to add another async doing `page.evaluateOnNewDocument(async ()` Then it runs, open the browser, but it doesn't navigate to the page, neither wait.

```
// mymodule.js
module.exports = {
  foo: async function (page) {
    await page.evaluateOnNewDocument(async () => {
      await page.goto('http://www.google.com');
      await page.waitFor(10000);  // That's Evil, I know
    });
  }
};
```

**UPDATE 2:** This is the actual code (suggested by @Ｈｏｎｇａｒｃ) I'm using, that doesn't throw errors, but doesn't work yet.

```
module.exports = {
  foo: function (page) {
    return page.evaluateOnNewDocument(async () => {
      await page.goto('http://www.google.com');
      await page.waitFor(10000);  // That's Evil, I know
    });
  }
};
```

Another approach would be acceptable, whilst we can use ie. `page.goto(<url>)` inside of `foo` function of `mymodule`. If it work, it'll be ok.

Comment: Are you sure page is set? I'd suggest checking what gets called first.

Comment: `page` was set with `const page = await browser.newPage();`

Comment: Your `foo` function in `module.exports` is missing an async

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's face it, the following function will run a code on the **browser context**

```
page.evaluateOnNewDocument
```

The error is not on the module itself, but how you are using it. `page` Object is not available on the browser context. So calling it is not the solution.

If you want to use page. in another module, you can safely do it this way,

```
// mymodule.js
module.exports = {
  foo: async function (page) {
      await page.goto('http://www.google.com');
      await page.waitFor(10000);
  }
};
```

Also make sure you have node version 7.6 or higher.

Answer (score 1):

You need mark your function is `async` to use `await`.
Try this:

```
// mymodule.js
module.exports = {
  foo: async function (page) {
    await page.evaluateOnNewDocument(async () => {
      await page.goto('http://www.google.com');
      await page.waitFor(10000);
    });
  }
};
```

This code will fix syntax of your code, but it wrong about logic.

- You don't need `await` in `module.exports.foo` of `mymodule.js`.
- `async` don't have competence use for function inside it.

You can try:

```
// mymodule.js
module.exports = {
  foo: function (page) {
    return page.evaluateOnNewDocument(async () => {
      await page.goto('http://www.google.com');
      await page.waitFor(10000);
    });
  }
};
```

Comment: I've updated my question to actually try to use the page object with `page.goto(<url>)` method, using async in my `foo` or the `return` doesn't make it work.

Comment: You use `async` and see `error`, can you tell me your error. and your version Node.js, thank you

Comment: If I use `async` here `page.evaluateOnNewDocument(async () => {` it doesn't throw errors and the browser is started, but automatically closes when it reach the `await page.goto(<url>)` method. If I don't use that `async` it throws the same first error, but in the inner block due to the `await` of `page.goto(<url>)`... My NodeJs version is `v8.9.4`

Comment: As first question, you don't say that callback in `evaluateOnNewDocument` use `await` so I don't add `async` to it, try this code again (edited), `async` can mark for `await` inside that function, not for all `await` inside child function

Comment: Your last edit, without `async` for the `foo` function and with `return` but having `page.evaluateOnNewDocument(async () => {` doesn't work yet. I removed the `preparePageForTests` method in `app.js` since I don't need it anymore when using a module. I've updated the question to show the actual code with the latest changes.